# jquery, double slidetoggle on mousenter

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

when my mouse is over a div .frame I want to slidetoggle 2 div: .content and .content2
I want .content to slidetoggle from bottom to top and .content2 from top to bottom.
The issue is both of them are slidetoggling from top to bottom, but when i only set my code to slidetoggle .content it does it from bottom to top.

My jQuery is

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.frame', function() { 
    var el = $(this);
    content = $(".content");
    content2 = $(".content2");
    content.css({"bottom":el.height(),"width":el.width()});
    content.html('ok ok ok ok');
    content2.html('ok ok ok ok');
    el.css("border-top-color","#FFFFFF");
    content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);  
    content2.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300); 
}).on('mouseleave','.frame', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    content = $(".content");
    content2 = $(".content2");
    content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300, function(){
        content.html('');
        el.css("border-top-color","#000000");
    });
    content2.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300)
});
```

here an exemple where both of the div are slidetoggeling : http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/utTcP/

and here an exemple where .content1 is slidetoggeling well:
http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/bgwSC/

Comment: You could use slideUp and slideDown explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after fiddling with this bad boy I got it to work how you want.

Here is the final JQuery:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.frame', function() { 
    var el = $(this);
    content = $(".content");
    content2 = $(".content2");
    content.css({"bottom":el.height(),"width":el.width()});
    content2.css({"top":el.height(),"width":el.width()});
    content.html('ok ok ok ok');
    content2.html('ok ok ok ok');
    el.css("border-top-color","#FFFFFF");
    el.css("border-bottom-color","#FFFFFF");
    content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
    content2.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
}).on('mouseleave','.frame', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    content = $(".content");
    content2 = $(".content2");
    content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300, function(){
        content.html('');
        el.css("border-top-color","#000000");
        el.css("border-bottom-color","#000000");
    });
    content2.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300)
});
```

I also made a few CSS changes to `content2`:

```
.content2 { 
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 1px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left: -1px;
}
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utTcP/1/)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot... i'm gonna study your code

Comment: No problem! The major changes were to `content2`. I basically treated it how you were already treating `content`. Since the position on content2 was not absolute like content, when it toggled it pulled down the whole div.